# By Switching the webhost, Magento top navigation vanished

Tags: magento, navigation

I migrated the site to hostgator and the top category menu vanished. I have tried all the solutions mentioned aroud the web., I am confused why this part is not loading.

everything else is going ok but in header.phtml where this `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>`  is called its not being displayed on frontend.

My header.phtml has the code this....

```
<div class="header-menu<?php if ($b['header']['menu_position'] == 'right') echo ' header-menu-right' ?>">
        <div class="<?php echo $containerClass ?>">
            <?php if ($b['header']['menu_position'] == 'left') : ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
            <div class="quick-access <?php if ($switcher_pos == 'middle' || $cart_pos == 'middle') echo 'quick-access1' ?> <?php if ($cart_pos == 'bottom' && $switcher_pos == 'middle') echo 'quick-access2'; ?>">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
                <?php if ($cart_pos == 'bottom') echo $cart_html; ?>
            </div>
            <?php else : ?>
            <div class="quick-access <?php if ($switcher_pos == 'middle' || $cart_pos == 'middle') echo 'quick-access1' ?> <?php if ($cart_pos == 'bottom' && $switcher_pos == 'middle') echo 'quick-access2'; ?>">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
                <?php if ($cart_pos == 'bottom') echo $cart_html; ?>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the theme structure is /app/design/frontend/(mytheme)/default/template/page/html/header.phtml

Any Help will highly be appreciated as its been aroud 10 hours i am stuck in this.

Comment: are the versions different of php ? if yes, consider what can be different in the both versions ? did you reindex ? clear the cache ?

Comment: Some `;` are missing. Are error warnings disabled ?

Comment: @Christophe... Yes I do reindexed and  i cleared the cache too but no output

Comment: @ClémentMalet no the error warnings are not disabled. Where are you pointing n the code where i missed " ; "

Comment: http://superdecals.net/ here is the link to the site

Comment: @user1631771 After several echos

Comment: The code as shown does not contain any syntax errors. The `;` can be left out in those places since there is only one statement in each PHP block. The reason must be something else – but what exactly, is hard to tell from the outside, so you will have to do some debugging yourself. First of all, enable proper error reporting/logging, and check the server’s log files.

Comment: @CBroe Yes surely the issue is something else...... I have been looking into it since last 10 hours but in vain :(

Comment: I'll get into the error log to check

Comment: Can you please tell us the php versions you are using ?